# Query using Variable returns always the Variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have created the following procedure to finally get the value (and not the column name at the end). However if using just the declared @ColumnName in the last query I just see the column name 'XXX' and not the value for XXX at that row.

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @ColumnName = (select column_name    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'History' and  ORDINAL_POSITION = 2 )

SELECT   @ColumnName from kat.[dbo].[History]
```

What I would like to get is the following results :

```
select XXX from kat.[dbo].[History]
```

Even the @ColumName has the value of XXX this is not working.

In the left I get my result (always the name of the column, and it the right is the desired value)

```
1-XXX, The value from XXX
2-XXX, the next value from XXX
3-XXX, the next value from XXX
```

Many thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: I assume History has many rows. About which value of XXX are you interested in?

Comment: Because @ColumnName is a varchar it will always return a string.  In SQL Server there are no column variable types.  Instead, you need to use a technique called [dynamic SQL (source MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic query

```
EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] ')
```

Comment: Can I also use the result of the dynamic query in order to insert values from this query? For example insert into Table  values ( ( EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] ')). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, Just need to use proper syntax like `INSERT TableName(ColumnName1)  EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] ')`

Comment: Thanks again, is it also compatible when inserting multiple columns ? For example : INSERT TableName(ColumnName1, ColumnName2) EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] '), datum from kat.[dbo].[History] . With just the insert of the dynamic query it works but wiith more value it does not compile

Comment: You need to select same number of columns columns in dynamic query as well.